# Validating inputs and using conditions seems to continue looping

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, break

As shown below, I'm providing the user with an option to spend points, I'm ensuring that the input contains either of 'y yes n no'. If the user would like to spend points he's prompted to select a number which differs the assignment of `v`, I'm ensuring the input is a number using `.isdigit()`. If the user wouldn't like to spend points `v` is simply assigned to `0.0`

```
while True:
    choice = raw_input('\nSpend points?')
    if choice.lower().strip() in "y yes n no".split():
        while True:
            if choice.lower().strip() in "y yes".split():
                c = raw_input('Enter Value 1-6: ')
                if c.isdigit() and int(c) <= 6:
                    if choice.lower().strip() in "y yes".split():
                        if c == '1':
                            v = 0.3
                        if c == '2':
                            v = 0.25
                        if c == '3':
                            v = 0.2
                        if c == '4':
                            v = 0.1
                        if c == '5':
                            v = 0.05
                        if c == '6':
                            v = 0.75
                        break
            if choice.lower().strip() in "n no".split():
                v = 0.0
                break
            else:
                continue
    else:
        continue

    print v
```

**However**, although the code works fine, after `v` seems to be printed successfully, the code will continue looping back to 'Would you like to spend credits?'

I believe the problem lies with my `break` statement, but I'm not sure where it's supposed to go.

Comment: You probably only need one loop here.

Comment: Are you trying to prompt the user repeatedly? If not, you probably don't need any loops at all.

Comment: I'm just trying to ensure that the inputs are as required

Comment: @Wyatt that's true, only one loop is enought, thanks for the comment I updated my answer if you want to see it

Comment: I'd suggest you check the yes/no choice in just one place because that will make the logic easier to follow, and if the user chooses `no` there's no need to enter the inner loop.

Comment: Take a look to the updated answer, now is even cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write the idea by doing this, and as @Wyatt used a map, is a nice idea use it too:

```
choice = raw_input('\nSpend points?')
v = 0.0
value_map = {
    1: 0.3,
    2: 0.25,
    3: 0.2,
    4: 0.1,
    5: 0.05,
    6: 0.75,
}
while not (choice.lower() in "y yes n no".split()):
  print("invalid input, valid input are 'y, yes, n, no'")
  choice = raw_input('\nSpend points?')

if choice.lower().strip() in "y yes".split():
    c = raw_input('Enter Value 1-6: ')
    while not(c.isdigit() and int(c) <= 6):
      print("please, enter a digit between 1 and 6")
      c = raw_input('Enter Value 1-6: ')

    v = value_map[int(c)]


print v
```

Comment: Ah, Alright, Got it. What loop is it breaking there though?

Comment: @LearningToPython I updated the answer, so it could be easier to understand, let me know if you got the idea, and don't forget to accept :)

Comment: Okay, That's great! Thanks

Comment: So I'm trying to get my head around the syntax, so while `choice` doesn't contain either yes/no type answers, then it checks if `choice` is a yes type answer - I'm not really understanding, why is it a while not loop and why does it work? ;/ Mind explaining the syntax?

Comment: @LearningToPython sure, look I, the first while is asking if the input is in NOT in "y-yes-n-no" meaning, it has to ask again to user to input again until the input is a valid one (the second else do that job, ask for a new input), then you ask if the input was a yes like, or a no like, and if it was no, you stop the while, if it was yes, you map the value

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, Hope you have a great day ;)

Comment: `choice.lower().strip() in "y-yes-n-no".split()` will always be `False` (unless the user happens to type in `'y-yes-n-no'`), so your `while` loop is essentially equivalent to `while True`.

Comment: @Wyatt that's true, I fixed that also, thanks, let me know if that satisfy now

Comment: I preferred the other version ;-)

Comment: @LearningToPython yeah but someone downvote it... to sad

Answer (score 1):

```
value_map = {
    1: 0.3,
    2: 0.25,
    3: 0.2,
    4: 0.1,
    5: 0.05,
    6: 0.75,
}

# Prompt user to spend points until they quit
while True:
    answer = raw_input('Spend points? y(es) n(o) q(uit) ')
    answer = answer.strip().lower()
    if not answer:
        continue
    if answer in ('q', 'quit'):
        print('Quit')
        # Break out of outer loop
        break
    elif answer in ('y', 'yes'):
        # Prompt until a valid selection is made
        while True:
            selection = raw_input('Value in 1-6 ')
            if not selection.isdigit():
                print 'Please select a number in 1-6'
                continue
            selection = int(selection)
            if selection < 1:
                print 'Selection out of range (too low)'
                continue
            if selection > 6:
                print 'Selection out of range (too high)'
                continue
            # Break out of inner loop
            break
        value = value_map[selection]
    elif answer in ('n', 'no'):
        value = 0.0
    else:
        print 'Please select one of y, n, or q'
        continue
    print value
```

Comment: Hey wyatt, nice work with the map, I will add it to my answer and redirct to yours, thanks and I will up vote